# How do I filter query results using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to create a component that provides typeahead autocomplete suggestions for users and groups. I'm using elasticsearch 6.5.3.  I created an index that contains the fields I want searched and 3 additional fields to filter by (isGroup,isUser,organizationId).  In some cases I want to use this component to search all users and group, sometimes just users or just groups or just users belonging to a specific organization.  I was planning to supply a filter along with the search terms depending on what the specific use case was.  I'm using nest to do the search, but I can't figure out how to do that. Is it possible to do this and if so how?  Am I going down the wrong path for this?  I mainly followed this [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) to create analyzer and stuff.  I can post my index if that will help but it's kind of long.

Here is a search with two of the items returned.

```
 return client.Search<UserGroupDocument>(s => s
            .Query(q=>q
                .QueryString(qs=>qs.Query("adm"))                    
            )
        );

    {
    "_index": "users_and_groups_autocomplete_index",
    "_type": "usergroupdocument",
    "_id": "c54956ab-c50e-481c-b093-f9855cc74480",
    "_score": 2.2962174,
    "_source": {
        "id": "c54956ab-c50e-481c-b093-f9855cc74480",
        "isUser": true,
        "isGroup": false,
        "name": "admin",
        "email": "admin@snapshotdesign.com",
        "organizationId": 2
    }
},
    {
        "_index": "users_and_groups_autocomplete_index",
        "_type": "usergroupdocument",
        "_id": "80f98d24-39e3-475d-9cb6-8f16ca472525",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
        "id": "80f98d24-39e3-475d-9cb6-8f16ca472525",
        "isUser": false,
        "isGroup": true,
        "name": "new Group",
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "Test User 1",
                "email": "test@example.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "admin",
                "email": "admin@snapshotdesign.com"
            }
        ],
        "organizationId": 0
    }
},
```

So depending on where I use this component I may want all of these return, just the user, just the group, or just the user in organization 2.

Here is my UserGroupDocument class

```
public class UserGroupDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsUser { get; set; }
    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public long OrganizationId { get; set; }

}
```

And the User class

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Based on Russ Cam's answer below, I altered the Must statement as shown below.  This gives me the filtering I wanted, but not the typeahead functionality.  I still have to type and entire word before I start getting matches.

```
.Must(mu => mu
    .QueryString(mmp => mmp
        .Query(searchTerms)
        .Fields(f => f
            .Field(ff => ff.Name)
            .Field(ff => ff.Users.Suffix("name"))
        )
    )
)
```

Here is the index I'm using.

```
{
"users_and_groups_autocomplete_index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "usergroupdocument": {
            "properties": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "autocomplete": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "isGroup": {
                    "type": "boolean"   
                },
                "isUser": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "autocomplete": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "organizationId": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "users": {
                    "properties": {
                        "email": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "autocomplete": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "autocomplete": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "provided_name": "users_and_groups_autocomplete_index",
            "creation_date": "1548363729311",
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                        ],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "autocomplete"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "token_chars": [
                            "digit",
                            "letter"
                        ],
                        "min_gram": "1",
                        "type": "edge_ngram",
                        "max_gram": "20"
                    }
                }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "Vxv-y58qQTG8Uh76Doi_dA",
            "version": {
                "created": "6050399"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add query you tried, expected result and sample data you have. It will help to understand the problem.

Comment: Does that help or do you need more info?  I'm happy to add anything, I just don't want to clutter up the question with a bunch of unhelpful json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way to combine multiple queries together:

1. query on search terms
2. query on `isGroup`
3. query on `isUser`
4. query on `organizationId`

and execute a search with some combination of these. This is where a compound query like the [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html#combining-queries) comes in. Given the following POCO

```
public class UserGroupDocument 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }
    public bool IsUser { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
}
```

We can start with

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")); 
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var isUser = true;
    var isGroup = true;
    var organizationId = "organizationId";

    var searchResponse = client.Search<UserGroupDocument>(x => x
        .Index(defaultIndex)
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Must(mu => mu
                    .QueryString(mmp => mmp
                        .Query("some admin")
                        .Fields(f => f
                            .Field(ff => ff.Name)
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Filter(fi => 
                    {
                        if (isUser)
                        {
                            return fi
                                .Term(f => f.IsUser, true);
                        }

                        return null;
                    }, fi =>
                    {
                        if (isGroup)
                        {
                            return fi
                                .Term(f => f.IsGroup, true);
                        }

                        return null;
                    }, fi => fi
                    .Term(f => f.OrganizationId, organizationId)
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

This will yield the following query

```
POST http://localhost:9200/default-index/usergroupdocument/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "isUser": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "isGroup": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "organizationId": {
              "value": "organizationId"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ],
            "query": "some admin"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If

- `isUser` is `false`, the `term` query filter on `isUser` field will not be included in the search query
- `isGroup` is `false`, the `term` query filter on `isGroup` field will not be included in the search query
- `organizationId` is `null` or an empty string, the `term` query filter on `organizationId` will not be included in the search query.

Now, we could go further and make `isGroup` and `isUser` nullable booleans (`bool?`). Then, when the value of either is `null`, the respective `term` query filter will not be included in the search query sent to Elasticsearch. This takes advantage of a feature known as *conditionless* queries in Nest, which is intended to make writing more complex queries easier. In addition, we can use [operator overloading on queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) to make it easier to write `bool` queries. This all means that we can refine the query down to

```cs
bool? isUser = true;
bool? isGroup = true;
var organizationId = "organizationId";

var searchResponse = client.Search<UserGroupDocument>(x => x
    .Index(defaultIndex)
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(mmp => mmp
            .Query("some admin")
            .Fields(f => f
                .Field(ff => ff.Name)
            )
        ) && +q
        .Term(f => f.IsUser, isUser) && +q
        .Term(f => f.IsGroup, isGroup) && +q
        .Term(f => f.OrganizationId, organizationId)
    )
);
```

Comment: The issues with this is that I don't get any results until I type an entire word.  So I would expect to see the admin user show up as a result after typing "ad" but it currently doesn't show up until I type "admin"

Comment: this worked once I removed the fields from the querystring function

Comment: @scott how text is analysed at index and search time governs which terms are generated and compared, for full text search. That's a large topic in itself, but start with: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

Comment: thanks for the answer @RussCam. How to add weights to different fields in your query?